# Spring Test DBUnit H2Connection Refused

Tags: spring-test, spring-test-mvc, spring-test-dbunit

I would like to create an integration test for my project and I am new to Spring Test DB Unit.  Unfortunately upon running the test I am encountering an error given below:

[Error: Connection refused: Connect localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqFg3.png)

I also added the the Base Test Config Class file where the configurations as well as how to connect to H2 database.

```
//import classes

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan( {"com.projects.person", "com.projects.commons"} )
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource( "classpath:application.properties" )
    public class BaseTestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
    {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Autowired
        private OperatingSystem operatingSystem;

        @Autowired
        private PropertiesFactory propertiesFactory;

        @Bean
        public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver()
        {
            UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix( "/WEB-INF/pages/" );
            resolver.setSuffix( ".jsp" );
            resolver.setViewClass( JstlView.class );
            return resolver;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan( "com.projects.person.model.db" );
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {

            String databaseUrl = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/persondb";
            if( operatingSystem.isWindows() )
            {
                databaseUrl = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/persondb";
            }

            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl( databaseUrl );
            dataSource.setUsername("sa");
            dataSource.setPassword("");
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public H2Connection dbUnitConnection() throws SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
            return new H2Connection(dataSource().getConnection(), "Person");
        }

        private Properties hibernateProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
            properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
            return properties;
        }

        @Bean
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
            HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = propertiesFactory.createTransactionManagerProperty();
            transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection is refused because the `databaseUrl` you specify requires a server that is already running and listening on a TCP port on `localhost`.

So you have two options.

1. Ensure that you have such an H2 database running on the `localhost`.
2. Use an embedded H2 database instead, as in the following example.

   - Further information can be found in the [Embedded database support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-embedded-database-support) section of the Spring reference manual.

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .generateUniqueName(true)
        .setType(H2)
        .build();
}
```